# How to add a 1/100 chance using random

Tags: java, random

I'm trying to make it so my game has a 1/100 chance to critical hit. I'm not sure how exactly to do this. I'm pretty sure this doesn't work:

```
criticalChance = crit.nextInt(1)/100;
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `criticalChance = crit.nextInt(1)/100.0`

Comment: nextInt(1) == 0, always. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I find this more elegant to use an int : `criticalChance = crit.nextInt(100); if (criticalChance == 0) ...`

Comment: It says what I'm trying to achieve: a 1% critical hit chance, 1/100

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
if (Math.random() > 0.99) {
    System.out.println("You have hit the 1 % chance!");
}
```

[`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) returns a `double` uniformly distributed in the unit interval [0, 1) so it will be greater than 0.99 with a probability of 1 %.

Comment: Not that it makes any actual difference but using `Math.random() <= 0.1` is a bit nicer since it 0.1 and 1% crit, and you can easily make it a variable that coresponds to the crit chance.

Comment: Yes, you might be right with that.  My personal reading is that we check whether a random variable surpasses a given threshold.  Therefore, I usually write `Math.random() > limit`.

Comment: `limit > Math.random()` would work just as well and will still correspond to the actual percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Do `(crit.nextInt(100))` and then use an if to check if the random is 50, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The `nextInt(int)` method returns an integer between `0`, inclusive, and the integer, exclusive. In your case, it will return an integer between `0`, inclusive, and `1`, exclusive. That means always a 0.

If you want to deal with probabilities, the canon way would be you use `nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt(int)`, that returns a number between `0.0` and `1.0`. And then you see if the number is lesser than your probability. In your case, 1% (= `0.01`), it should be like:

```
if(crit.nextDouble() < 0.01) //will happen 1% of the time
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Random` class and generate a float with it. It will be a number in the range between 0.0 and 1.0. So to have a chance of 1 in a hundred, check if it is smaller than 1/100 == 0.01.

```
Random crit = new Random();
boolean isCriticalHit = crit.nextFloat() < 0.01;
```